# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex - Android Studio 3.0 stable

Tags: android, gradle, merge, dex, android-studio-3.0

I made:

- In "Settings"->"Android SDK"->"SDK Tools" Google Play services is checked and installed v.46
- Removed folder /.gradle
- "Clean Project"
- "Rebuild Project

Error is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

**Project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asanquran.mnaum.quranasaanurdutarjuma"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'


    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.3.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: you didn't added multidex support in defaultConfig. Try adding this: defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }

Comment: I've tried it, but then its giving a list of errors

Comment: show your errors

Comment: don't use apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' in your dependencies. see my edit for your question.

Comment: no, its not solving the problem. Problem is still alive.

Comment: Have you got the solution, because i am facing same issue in android studio 3.0 ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: I think you should recheck your dependencies thoroughly.

Comment: Try 'compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was due to Android Studio's latest version (at that time).
I tried it after a long time then the issue gone.

Answer (score 40):

1. Go to `<project>/app/` and open `build.gradle` file
2. Add the following line to the `defaultConfig` and `dependencies` sections

```
android {
  ...

  defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true // ADD THIS LINE
  }
}

...

dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: only multiDexEnabled true was enough, thanx.

Comment: got the error for react-native-pdf. This solution works for me

Comment: thanks, I updated min sdk version and then encountered this error.  Worked for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 21):

I know it's too late to update.I had same issue on my project.

**Possible Reasons**

1. If you have added module in your project and that module has support libraries or any google play services libs which has different version then your app.
2. If you are using any open source library in your project and that library internally using any of libraries that your are also using in your project.

**Solutions**

- If it is case 1 in your project then update your library versions and make it same in your project and module.
- Check your dependencies tree using below command and see if any mismatch in dependencies.

  ```
  ./gradlew :app:dependencies
  ```
- You can exclude particular module from any dependencies like below.

  ```
  implementation('com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.4') {
    transitive = true
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
  }
  ```
- In above example, It will exclude the ***com.android.support*** group from ***consent-library dependencies.***
- You can also remove particular module as well.

  ```
   compile ('junit:junit:4.12'){
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module:'hamcrest-core'
    }
  ```
- In above example it will exclude ***hamcrest-core*** from ***org.hamcrest***.

Comment: Great! It was the reason #1. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

I got the same problem, adding `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to my `build.gradle` helped me:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having a fit with this, and none of the answers I found worked.  Finally found a solution -- sharing it here although I can't tell you definitively how to find which is the offending dependency -- maybe you'll have to do some trial and error.

In my **build.gradle** (Module:app) I added this exclude clause:

```
    compile ('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2')
        { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
```

Answer (score 3):

I did exact as the hint in the image except changed 11.0.4 to 11.8.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

[image: Unable to merge dex]

Answer (score 3):

When the same issue appeared, my `build.gradle` already had the following was already there:

```
android {
  ...

  defaultConfig {
   ...
  multiDexEnabled true 
   }
}

...

dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  
}
```

I cleaned the project, and then run build again, and the issue was gone.

Comment: May I ask how you cleaned it?

Comment: From android studio, in the menu, I guess under build, you find "clean". @helloworld331

Comment: Thanks @fahima, I think I found a way with cli which is in `android` folder `./gradlew clean`. But I appreciate your comment letting me know another way :)

Answer (score 2):

while creating Flutter Project, I encountered this issue. What I did is, opened *MyProject/android/app/build.gradle* file and added **multiDexEnabled** *true* inside defaultConfig tag as given below:

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "Your Application ID Here"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i change all **com.android.support:** libraries to 27.1.0 and it works