# DexArchiveMergerException when generating build

Tags: android, apk, android-multidex

I am facing exception when generating build(Build APKs). Below is the exception faced.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives

I tried to figure out the cause with my libraries tree view. And I referred below links

```
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977267/com-android-builder-dexing-dexarchivemergerexception-unable-to-merge-dex-andr
2. https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/386
```

And my app's dependency tree view is below

```
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1
|    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.8.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0 -> 27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0 -> 27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.0 -> 27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
+--- com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:1.8.0
|    \--- com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter:1.8.0
+--- com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:1.8.0
|    \--- com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter:1.8.0
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|         |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
+--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
+--- com.github.IntruderShanky:Sectioned-RecyclerView:2.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0
|    +--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1 -> 3.10.0
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0 -> 3.10.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
+--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6
+--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1 -> 1.1.6
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0 -> 27.1.1
+--- me.himanshusoni.quantityview:quantity-view:1.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.github.matrixxun:MaterialBadgeTextView:c5a27e8243
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- ch.acra:acra:4.7.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.5
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 27.1.1
+--- com.xwray:passwordview:1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5) -> 4.38.1
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.38.1
|    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|    |    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.38.1
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.38.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0
+--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
+--- project :enetslib-release_1.2.1
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `multiDexEnabled true` in your project-level build.gradle.

Like this-

```
defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 
         targetSdkVersion 27

         // Add this line
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
```

Comment: Tried with multiDexEnabled true. Still getting same exception.